# Pandas Group BY implementation required

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
             id              Name  ...  start_date   end_date
0          2108  Ahsen Javed Khan  ...  2018-02-17 2018-02-18
1          2108  Ahsen Javed Khan  ...  2018-01-23 2018-01-24
2          2108  Ahsen Javed Khan  ...  2012-11-15 2012-12-31
3          2108  Ahsen Javed Khan  ...  2015-05-01 2015-10-31
4          2108  Ahsen Javed Khan  ...  2017-10-01 2017-12-31
```

such that i have 500K records, now i want the details of all id and i don't want to remove duplication of id's.

I want to have output like below.

```
             id              Name  ...  start_date   end_date
0          2108  Ahsen Javed Khan  ...  2018-02-17 2018-02-18
1                                  ...  2018-01-23 2018-01-24
2                                  ...  2012-11-15 2012-12-31
3                                  ...  2015-05-01 2015-10-31
4                                  ...  2017-10-01 2017-12-31
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['id','name']).agg(start_date=('start_date','min'), end_date=('end_date','max'))` ?

Comment: If need something else let me know. Now understand your question  need remove duplicated values per column `id` and `Name`

Comment: actually i need to map all other columns with respect to ID..... so once i call particular id all relevant columns should be called off...what about groupby.size() function..